# jQuery slider is not hiding content due to overflow:hidden; being ignored?

Tags: css

**Liver View:** https://tornhq.com/WorkingOn/InteractiveMap/Replaced-With-Divs.html

Hello,

The purpose of my jQuery slider at the side, not to be mistaken for the bottom slider, is not working brilliantly, however my overflow is being ignored for some reason and I just cannot figure out why. I could really do with some help in resolving this problem.

---

**EDIT:**

```
.testdiv {
    float:left;
    width:978px;
    font:normal .75em/1.5em 'Lucida Grande', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    margin:1em auto;
    text-align:left;
    text-shadow:0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.5);
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

The above is the main div, of which everything is in apart from that div being inside another for the background. My container moves right outside of this container however your still able to see it.

---

Thank you for any time spend in following up with my question.
Best Regards,
Tim

Comment: You should post the relevant code in your question.

Comment: also fix this error in your code..
     throw "Syntax error, unrecognized expression: " + a

Comment: also the overflow is not been over written written elsewhere.. what are you trying to do?

Comment: @Marcel I do not know what the relevant code is, I am not sure whether it is to do with my moving content or the actual div. I'll update it in a moment.

Comment: @jycr753 I cannot find '" + a –" anywhere. As for the overflow:hidden; it is the main div. See edit question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set `#Map-Selection-Info` to `position: relative;` not `absolute`.
Otherwise `absolute` kills the influence of `overflow`.

Comment: Brilliant! I feel stupid now. I knew it would be somethng really obvious! Thanks!